# How do you extract the index postion from mp4s with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp4

I know you can extract metadata from mp4s but I want to pull specifically the index point which is in Moov Atom.  Any input is greatly appreciated.

If anyone knows of a program that can read the index position of an mp4 would be even better.

Comment: Check this link: [Apple Developer - QuickTime Tools](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/quicktimeintro/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

For an example in AS3, see http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

This utility locates the MOOV atom and then, if necessary, moves it to the front of the mp4 for progress streaming.